# I am using MacBook Air M1 and my XCode 13 preview get crashes on canvas as well as on the simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, simulator

My swift preview gets crash on XCode 13

```
import SwiftUI

struct WeatherView: View {
    var weather: ResponseBody
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            VStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5){
                    Text(weather.name)
                        .bold().font(.title)
                    
                    Text("Today, \(Date().formatted(.dateTime.month().day().hour().minute()))")
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                Spacer()
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        VStack(spacing: 20) {
                            Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill")
                                .font(.system(size: 40))
                            
                            Text(weather.weather[0].main)

                        }
                        
                        .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Text(weather.main.feelsLike.roundDouble() + "")
                            .font(.system(size: 100))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .padding()
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 80)
                    
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ac/4a/0e/ac4a0ea3d1691ee48f7b7680e829dd5d.png")) { image in image
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 350)
                    } placeholder: {
                        ProgressView()
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
                
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                    Text("Weather now")
                        .bold().padding(.bottom)
                    
                    HStack {
                        WeatherRow(logo: "thermometer", name: "Min temp", value: (weather.main.tempMin.roundDouble() + "°"))
                        
                        Spacer()
                        WeatherRow(logo: "thermometer", name: "Max temp", value: (weather.main.tempMax.roundDouble() + "°"))
                    }
                    HStack {
                        WeatherRow(logo: "wind", name: "wind speed", value: (weather.wind.speed.roundDouble() + "m/s"))
                        
                        Spacer()
                        WeatherRow(logo: "Humidity", name: "humidity", value: (weather.main.humidity.roundDouble() + "%"))
                    }
                
                    
                }
                
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding()
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 0.501, saturation: 0.8, brightness: 0.763))
                .background(.white)
                .cornerRadius (radius: 20, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
            }
            
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        .background(Color(hue: 0.501, saturation: 0.8, brightness: 0.763))
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}

struct WeatherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WeatherView(weather: previewWeather)
    }
}
```

I am making a weather app using swift on Xcode 13. I don't why but it shows a fatal error if try to run a preview. Also, it just shows a white blank screen if I try to run my code on a simulator. Could anyone tell me how to do fix it? I tried reopening Xcode and it doesn't work. I even tried to restart my MacBook but still, it won't work.

Comment: Try removing pieces of code from your view to see if you can get the error to disappear.  Or post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Are you sure about the contents of previewWeather and weather (no nil or unset optional ?)

Comment: This is a common thing in Xcode. It does not always provide you the "Apple Experience" you would expect. The simulator almost never works at my side and is just stuck. I gave up a while ago but you might try to clear the build folder and restart Xcode. Give it some time to index and it should work...

Comment: What is the crash? What line throws it? What does the diagnostics button say on the corner?